# What is the effect when the sum does not use get() ? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have 1 million data

When I do `sum` use `get()` like this :

```
$cache = Summary::where('type', $type)
                ->where('keys->year', '=', (string)$year)
                ->get();
$summary = $cache->sum('summary');
```

It's very slowly

But when I do `sum` without use `get()` like this :

```
$cache = Summary::where('type', $type)
                ->where('keys->year', '=', (string)$year);
$summary = $cache->sum('summary');
```

It's very fast

Whether it is okay if the `sum` without using `get`?

Comment: without the get() your statement does not get executed.

Comment: @Friedrich Roell, I do `sum` without `get`, it's executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ->get() you are actually retrieving the information from the database. If you have a lot of rows this can slow a query down a lot.

The ->sum() just sums the rows, a method that is lightweight in comparison to ->get().

If you don't actually need the information from the rows, but only the sum of all rows you should only use ->sum() and not ->get() as well. You don't need to use ->get() to have the ->sum() working.

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates) containing the following examples:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
$price = DB::table('orders')->max('price');
```

Both do not use ->get() in order to ->count() or ->max().

I guess you could even do:

```
$sum = Summary::where('type', $type)->where('keys->year', '=', (string)$year)->sum();
```

Comment: Whether that means the conclusion is that it can be done? No effect?

Comment: If you only want to sum the rows not using ->get() has not effect in this case no.

Answer (score 1):

Using get() fetches all the data and then you're manually finding the sum on the collection of retrieved data. But when you don't use get() `$cache` is still a query and fetching sum on the query would run a aggregate query on the database instead of fetching all the data.

```
$summary = Summary::where('type', $type)
    ->where('keys->year', '=', (string)$year)
    ->sum('summary');
```

Comment: Whether that means the conclusion is that it can be done? No effect. For example error etc

Comment: @samueltoh the conclusion is that this is the right way to do it, without using get(). There are no errors or issues, it's the correct way to go about it.